# Open source did a major update and I can't merge

Tags: git

So I have a fork of a project on Github (http://www.github.com/intridea/grape), and they did a major merge of a branch (frontier -> master). It looks like a rebase.

When I go into my fork and run git rebase upstream/master, I get a merge conflict. I'm not sure why but it fails on the README. I didn't make any commits to the readme.

What should I do to get my master up to date without destroying any of my forks branches?

Comment: stash your changes and then apply them after the pull?

Comment: I have no changes. Clean working tree.

Answer (score 0):

I gather from your comment that you have no commits of your own on the master branch that you have to keep. In that case you can just `git fetch` all the remote commits and then make the `master` head point to the right hash. Either use `git reset <hash>` or just edit the `.git/ref/heads/master` file by hand.

You may lose the ability to rebase your branch changes on master and ff-merge them, but there's always the regular merge.

Answer (score 0):

If upstream did rebase the branch (a big no-no), the conflict is probably coming from a pre-rebase upstream commit (that changed `README`) being merged with a post-rebase upstream commit (that also changed `README`).

If you have not made any commits in your local repository, you can simply `git reset --hard @{u}` to force your local branch to match the upstream branch.

If you have made commits, and the upstream branch was rebased, then the fix is very complicated and depends on the state of your repository.  (This is why it's rude to rebase commits that have already been shared with others.)  For general help, see the section called "Recovering From Upstream Rebase" in `git help rebase`.